# listview inside listview with firebase on android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, adapter

I am trying to create a list view of data from firebase. Each item has a `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

I also want to that every time I click on the `TextView` to enter a new `ListView` associated somehow with this item. The second list also has items with `TextView` and `ImageButton` (each time I update the list according to its type).

The problem is that, I cannot understand, how to separate the implementation of  `OnClickItemView` between the `TextView` and `ImageView`.

This is my adapter :

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    List <ObjectItem> items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Adapter(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public Adapter(Activity activity, List<HistoryItem> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
        inflater= activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_item, viewGroup, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtMsg = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            holder.btn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        ObjectItem item = items.get(position);
        holder.txtMsg.setText(item.getTxt());

        if(item.type().equals("LIST_1")){
            holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.save);
        } else {
            holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void updateRecords(List<HistoryItem> items){
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtMsg;
        ImageView btn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement multiple `ViewHolder` based on the `ViewType` returned from your `getItemViewType` function of your adapter. Here's an implementation [in github](https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview), for your understanding.

The implementation shows two different lists to be populated in a single `RecyclerView`. You might consider implementing the same idea here. Just return a separate view type based on the items in your list which is passed to the adapter.

On the other hand, if you are thinking of different implementation for your `onClickItemView` function, you may have the same behaviour by implementing the `onClickListener` on your `TextView` or `ImageView`. In your code inside `getView` function, you might consider implementing `onClickListener` separately while you are checking condition for setting the background of your button.

```
if(item.type().equals("LIST_1")){
    holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.save);
    holder.txtMsg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Your implementation here
        }
    });
} else {
    holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
    holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.save);
    holder.txtMsg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Separate implementation here
        }
    });
}
```